# How to install YoloV3 in python using some codes in anaconda?

Tags: python-3.7

[Anaconda Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRVt5.png)

I used to follow this article: https://medium.com/deepquestai/train-object-detection-ai-with-6-lines-of-code-6d087063f6ff, but I can't proceed because I can't install YoloV3. The line which I followed here is `pip install https://github.com/OlafenwaMoses/ImageAI/releases/download/essential-v4/pretrained-yolov3.h5` but it appears error on anaconda.

The output is Cannot unpack file c:\users\appdata\local\temp\pip-unpack-vo7bb6\pretrained-yolov3.h5 (downloaded from c:\users\appdata\local\temp\pip-req-build-pfzpqr, content-type: application/octet-stream); cannot detect archive format
Cannot determine archive format of c:\users\appdata\local\temp\pip-req-build-pfzpqr

Comment: Are you using Python3?

Comment: yes, python 3.7 :( I also tried it on python 2.7.

Comment: Have you installed the h5py package via pip in your environment?

Comment: yes, it says "requirement already satisfied"

Comment: Which line is giving you the error from the article? Edit your question to reference which part is giving you the error - don't answer here in comments to make it easier for others to help you.

Comment: Thank you. I also put image and re-edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions in the article exactly. The YOLO model is not a PIP package but a file to download and put in the same folder as your other code. It's not using pip but [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html)

```
!wget https://github.com/OlafenwaMoses/ImageAI/releases/download/essential-v4/pretrained-yolov3.h5
```

Comment: The output is " '!wget' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file." Is there any other commands aside from !wget?

Comment: If you not using Google Colab but your local machine instead - remove the "!"  in front of wget - rest of line should be the same. The '!' is unique to Google Colab and not needed for local machine.

Comment: I tried to install wget package and put `python -m wget`, it works! Thank you for giving me an idea

Comment: OK - I am going to vote to close this question since this is a one time case and not likely to be encountered by others.